# Why does JSON.stringify() returns undefined when passed a replacer function?

Tags: javascript, json

When I pass a function as the second parameter into `JSON.stringify()` and test for the value of the key, I get undefined. Any idea why?

```
var person = {
    name: "Siddharth",
    age: 23,
    sex: 0,
    phone: 12345
};

personString = JSON.stringify(person, personFilter, 2);
console.log(personString);

function personFilter(key, value) {
    if (key == "age") {
        return value;
    }
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mggut/)

Comment: Because the initial object is the first thing given. It has the key `""`. In that and all other cases not represented by your `if`, you're returning `undefined`. Be sure to return `value` for every item that should be kept, including the object itself.

Comment: ...here's the fixed demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mggut/1/

Comment: @cookiemonster, so an `||` condition checking for a `!key` should do the trick then? Why is the entire object passed first? And how is its key ""? Could you elaborate a little more. I want to understand this, not just fix it.

Comment: Yes, that would work too. I suppose the object is passed just to be consistent so that every value can be represented. Since the outer structure itself is a value, they include it. The key is an empty string because there's no structure in which it's nested, so there's no key to pass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to get "Age", you would use an array instead of a function:

```
personString = JSON.stringify(person, ["age"], 2);
```

[If you use a function, it is getting the whole object first](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_native_JSON#The_replacer_parameter)

> The replacer parameter can be either a function or an array. As a function, it takes two parameters, the key and the value being stringified. The object in which the key was found is provided as the replacer's this parameter. **Initially it gets called with an empty key representing the object being stringified**, and it then gets called for each property on the object or array being stringified. It should return the value that should be added to the JSON string, as follows:
>
> - If you return a Number, the string corresponding to that number is used as the value for the property when added to the JSON string.
>     If you return a String, that string is used as the property's value when adding it to the JSON string.
> - If you return a Boolean, "true" or "false" is used as the property's value, as appropriate, when adding it to the JSON string.
> - If you return any other object, the object is recursively stringified into the JSON string, calling the replacer function on each property, unless the object is a function, in which case nothing is added to the JSON string.
> - If you return undefined, the property is not included in the output JSON string.

As for *why* the key for the entire object is empty... it's really the only option - anything else could be a key for a property of the object, an empty key is the *only* thing they could use that you would then be able to know - inside the transformer function - "this is definitely the entire object", regardless of what the object contained.

So in your case, it would look like:

```
personString = JSON.stringify(person, personFilter, 2);

function personFilter(key, value) {
    if (key == "age" || key == "") {
        return value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't know you could pass an array of keys. I only knew about the function.

Comment: No, I understand that I can pass an array. I want to know why it passes the entire object first. And why the key for the entire object is "".

Comment: @Siddharth from the quoted text above "Initially it gets called with an empty key representing the object being stringified". `key` is always a string, because objects keys in JS are always strings. So an empty `key` is an emtpy string, or `""`.

Comment: Yes! Got it. The post was edited with it and I commented before that. Waiting for another minute to accept the answer.

Comment: Okay, one last question. Please confirm if I am correct with the following statement. The first time the function is called, `JSON.stringify()` returns the entire object's key which is "", the if block in case of a `if (key === "age" || key === "")` gets executed and since I return the value which in this case is the entire object, the function gets recursively called on the whole object.

Comment: That is correct - not sure if recursive per se, but it definitely gets called twice - if you `console.log('test')` in it then it will log `test` twice.